# "I hope I can" vs "I wish I could" proper usage

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

- I **hope** I **can** go to the beach
- I **wish** I **could** go to the beach

Am I right to assume that both of these sentences are grammatically correct? And that their difference only lies in the meaning you want to convey?

For example, I will use "I hope I can" when I'm trying to say that there is a future possibility that I can go, or that there is a strong possibility it can happen (just not now).

But for "I wish I could", I will use that when I know that there's no chance I could go, or there's no chance it will take place.

...Or am I wrong?

I do know that grammatically, the following are wrong:

- I **hope** I **could** go to the beach (because 'hope' usually uses the present tense)
- I **wish** I **can** go to the beach (because 'wish' usually uses the past tense)

Comment: "I wish I can" might be correct in the context where you were closing your eyes and making a wish with an expectation it would come true, for instance if you were in a fairy tale. But normally you wish for things that are unlikely, and use "could" for things that are unlikely. "I wish I can" isn't really ungrammatical, it's just that some combinations of meaning are unlikely to occur together. ("Could" in this sense is a modal verb not a past tense of "can" according to https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/could ).